# One function calls another function without any specifc call in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I really need help, because I don't know why this is happening.

I have an Angular webapp with a Firebase backend. My webapp shows 7 random products from a products collection in Firebase. This 7 random products should be stored so that, the users can see it on different devices. 
But if i call my savemethod, something weird is happening. The save method, calls a the method, who generates the 7 random products and i don't know why, because i don't call it expecially.

Heres my code:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  schedulenumbers: ISchedule = { numbers: [] }; //Just an Object with an array of numbers in it
  length: number = 0; //lenght is needed to show or hite the list in the template
  filteredproducts: IProduct[] = [];
  numbers: number[] = []; // the numbers to filter the products

  constructor(private productservice: ProductService) {
    console.log("constructor wurde aufgerufen");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredproducts = [];
    console.log("ngOnInit was called")
    //get the numbers from the database
    this.productservice.getnumbers().subscribe(
      numbers => {
        this.numbers = numbers.numbers;
      }
    );
    //get all products from the database collection
    this.productservice.getallproducts().pipe(
      map((products) => {
        this.length = products.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          this.filteredproducts.push(product[this.numbers[i]]);
        }
        return this.filteredproducts;
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  getRandomproducts(): void {
    this.filteredproducts = [];
    this.numbers = [];
    console.log("getRandomproducts was called");
    this.productservice.getallproducts().pipe(
      map(products => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          this.numbers[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length + 1)
          if (products[this.numbers[i]] == undefined) {
            i -= 1;
          }
          else {
            this.filteredproducts.push(products[this.numbers[i]]);
          }
        }
        console.log(this.numbers);
        return this.filteredproducts;
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  saveNumbers(): void {
    console.log("savenumbers was called")
    console.log(this.numbers);
    this.schedulenumbers.numbers = this.numbers;
    console.log(this.filteredproducts.length);
    this.productservice.updatenumbers(this.schedulenumbers);
  }

}
```

Here is the code for the productservice:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  Productcollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<IProduct>;
  schedulenumbers: AngularFirestoreDocument<ISchedule>;
  numbers: Observable<ISchedule>
  Products$: Observable<IProduct[]>;

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.auth.currentUser.then(user => {
      this.productcollection = this.firestore.collection(`${user.uid}`);
      this.schedulenumbers =    this.firestore.collection(`${user.uid}`).doc("numbers")
    })
  }

  getallproducts() {
    return this.Products$ = this.Productcollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'ProductId' }).pipe(
      map(products =>
        products.filter(product => product.ProductId != 'numbers')
      )
    );

  }

  getnumbers() {
    return this.numbers = this.schedulenumbers.valueChanges();
  }

  updatenumbers(numbers: ISchedule) {
    this.schedulenumbers.update(numbers)
  }

  addrecipe(product: IProduct) {
    this.Productcollection.add(product);
  }

}
```

I have attached a picture from the Firefox console that shows that if I press the button for the getRandomproducts method twice and then I press the button for the saveNumbers method, strangely white from the saveNumbers method, the for loop of getrandomproduct number method is called and in the filteredproducts array are not longer only 7, but much more products. But why?

[Firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtT5O.png)

Comment: Can you also post the code from productService, especially the getallproducts method? I am thinking this may happen because the observable returned by this method is not completed when you receive the first set of data, and it emits two more times.

Comment: @Inout Gabriel Pitigoi thanks for your comment. i added the code for the productService to the post.